# Insert row in table for each result of query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have 2 tables in my database (friends / guestbook).

I'm using the following query to select all the friends for a specific user.

```
SELECT FID FROM `friends` as F WHERE UID = 1
```

What I'd like to do is insert a row on the 'guestbook' table for each result that is returned from the query above.

```
INSERT INTO `guestbook` (`FID`, `UID`, `message`) VALUES ('FID SHOULD BE EQUAL TO FID FROM PREVIOUS QUERY', '1', 'message goes here!')
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO `guestbook` (`FID`, `UID`, `message`)
    SELECT FID, 1, 'message'
    FROM `friends` as F
    WHERE UID = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked and I was able to insert 20k rows far faster than I anticipated.